# Return data back to ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a php code (no functions, just direct code) which queries a data base stores values 
in an array and returns the array

```
<?php
//Query the database and fetch some results
    $array["min_date"] = $arr['min(date)'];
    $array["max_date"] = $arr['max(date)'];
    $array['query'] = $query;

    echo $arr['min(date)'].'</br>';
    echo $arr['max(date)'];

    return $array;
?>
```

this is my jquery ajax call

```
function date(){
    $temp = $('select[name=people_name]').val();
    $name = $temp;
    $table = 'myTablename'; 
    $url = "/myurl/php/get_date.php?name="+$name+"&table="+$table;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $url,
        success: function(data) {
         document.getElementById("from_date").value = data['min_date'];
         document.getElementById("to_date").value = data['max_date'];
        }
    });
}
```

when I echo the php variables I do get the data which I want. but logging the jquery variables the give me result as undefined.

maybe the php return data is not fetches by ajax success(data)? or do I need to have a function in my php code? how do I fetch returned array in my jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't actually perform a query. In fact, it does nothing at all except echo a couple of undefined variables.

Comment: It does perform a query.. but I have hidden that code since it is irrelevant to this question. and I can successfully fetch the data inside my array variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your PHP**

```
//Query the database and fetch some results
$array["min_date"] = $arr['min(date)'];
$array["max_date"] = $arr['max(date)'];
$array['query'] = $query;
echo json_encode($array); //add this
```

**In ajax call**

```
function date(){
    $temp = $('select[name=people_name]').val();
    $name = $temp;
    $table = 'myTablename'; 
    $url = "/myurl/php/get_date.php?name="+$name+"&table="+$table;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json', //add dataType
        url: $url,
        success: function(data) {
         document.getElementById("from_date").value = data.min_date;
         document.getElementById("to_date").value = data.max_date;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try encoding the array in php side with json_encode().

Comment: as per php documentation I replaced my return statement with this =>> return json_encode($array).. but my log still says data['max_date'] & data['min_date'] is undefined.

Comment: I get the result in this format:    {"min_date":"2013-03-05","max_date":"2013-10-14"}      .. but how do I get the values in jquery?

Comment: var json = JSON.parse(jsonString) or via jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/